# mysqli_prepare query returning false

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, parameters

I am attempting to bind params to a sql statement using `call_user_func_array` as describe on [Dynamically Bind Params in Prepared Statements with MySQLi](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli); however, my `mysqli_prepare` keeps returning false.

Here is my data function that is called to store data:

```
function storeData($form_data, $table_name, $cxn){
if(!is_array($form_data)){
    return false;
    exit();
}
$types = str_repeat("s", count($form_data));
$params = array();
$params[] = &$types;
$keys = array_keys($form_data);
$values = array_values($form_data);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    $params[] = &$values[$i];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name (" . implode(',', $keys) . ") VALUES (" .
    implode(',', array_fill(0, count($values), '?')) . ")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ";
$updates = implode(',', array_map(function($col) {
    return "$col = VALUES($col)";
}, $keys));
$sql .= $updates;

if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cxn, $sql)){
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
    return mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

Here is my `$sql` string at time of prepare:

```
$sql"INSERT INTO interest (Baseball,Basketball,Camping,Canoeing,Cycling,Football,Gaming,Golf,Hiking,Parks,Photography,Runway,Skydiving,Soccer,Username) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Baseball = VALUES(Baseball),Basketball = VALUES(Basketball),Camping = VALUES(Camping),Canoeing = VALUES(Canoeing),Cycling = VALUES(Cycling),Football = VALUES(Football),Gaming = VALUES(Gaming),Golf = VALUES(Golf),Hiking = VALUES(Hiking),Parks = VALUES(Parks),Photography = VALUES(Photography),Runway = VALUES(Runway),Skydiving = VALUES(Skydiving),Soccer = VALUES(Soccer),Username = VALUES(Username)"
```

Here is my `$params` and `$key` outputs:

```
$keysarray[15]
$keys[0]"Baseball"
$keys[1]"Basketball"
$keys[2]"Camping"
$keys[3]"Canoeing"
$keys[4]"Cycling"
$keys[5]"Football"
$keys[6]"Gaming"
$keys[7]"Golf"
$keys[8]"Hiking"
$keys[9]"Parks"
$keys[10]"Photography"
$keys[11]"Runway"
$keys[12]"Skydiving"
$keys[13]"Soccer"
$keys[14]"Username"

$paramsarray[16]
$params[0]"sssssssssssssss"
$params[1]"0"
$params[2]"0"
$params[3]"0"
$params[4]"0"
$params[5]"0"
$params[6]"0"
$params[7]"0"
$params[8]"0"
$params[9]"0"
$params[10]"0"
$params[11]"0"
$params[12]"0"
$params[13]"0"
$params[14]"0"
$params[15]"test0613"

$valuesarray[15]
$values[0]"0"
$values[1]"0"
$values[2]"0"
$values[3]"0"
$values[4]"0"
$values[5]"0"
$values[6]"0"
$values[7]"0"
$values[8]"0"
$values[9]"0"
$values[10]"0"
$values[11]"0"
$values[12]"0"
$values[13]"0"
$values[14]"test0613"
```

Comment: You seem to have overlooked the parts of the blog post that show what to do `if($stmt === false) { ...`

Comment: @Michael `if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($cxn, $sql))` does exactly that. The `if()` statement checks if the `$stmt`  is false. If the express returns false $stmt will be 0.

Comment: Yes, I understand that... but you have shown no `else` block, that should provide a subsequent check of `$cxn->error`, which, along with `$cxn->errno` and `$cxn->sqlstate` contain the answer to your question of **why** it was false.

Comment: @Michael `mysqli_error()==""` & `mysqli_sqlstate($cxn)=="0000"`

Comment: That's unexpected.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot you sent me down the right path to solve this issue. So i did find some other reporting measures that allowed me to produce the error which was an undefined column in my table

Comment: Great... in addition to the citation of the other answer, would you also include some details from the other answer in your answer, below, for the benefit of future visitors?  Or, we can close this as a duplicate of the question where the solution is already found.

Answer (score 1):

There error existed in a column i was attempting to map which did not exist. The error procedure was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662488/how-to-get-mysqli-error-in-different-environments), which allowed me to produce fatal errors that noted a column did not exist in the table I was referencing.